# Transfer funds to and from Plaid Sandbox Bank Account with Stripe ACH

Tags: stripe-payments, plaid

I'm building a demo app where I want to transfer money to and from the test bank account provided in plaid sandbox (the app is just for proof of product so I would like to avoid using live credentials). I use plaid to validate bank account details and a stripe integration to handle ACH charges. I have everything working from a code perspective and end up getting a bank account token which I charge, however the charge is on the stripe test bank account and not the plaid sandbox test bank account. I see in the docs this is expected behavior (not sure why), but I want to be able to make an ach charge on the plaid test bank account. I know this may not be the best place to ask this, but if I spend another second talking with Ethan the Stripe AI Bot, I might lose it. Hoping a stripe/plaid expert can help me out, thanks!

Comment: Per [Plaid's docs](https://support.plaid.com/hc/en-us/articles/360008270974-Plaid-Stripe-testing):

> Regardless of which Plaid Sandbox account_id is provided in the /processor/stripe/bank_account_token/create request, the test mode stripe_bank_account_token that is generated will always be associated with the Stripe test account and routing number. The test mode stripe_bank_account_token will be associated with the Stripe account that you linked in the Plaid Dashboard.

Comment: Yes I read this, thank you! Does this mean there is no way to demo withdrawing/depositing funds and have it reflected in the plaid sandbox test bank account?

Comment: That's correct. Stripe test mode never actually moves (even test/fake) money outside of Stripe.